# webpages not loading properly in android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to load a website in android webview which has pretty good design but in webview only html content is showing. I don't have experience with Web but I think the CSS is not loading.

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    webView.loadUrl(myURL);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

[image: Login page in android webview]

Its working fine in iOS webview and in browsers.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: add some code that resulted in the above image.

Comment: There is no issue in the code. Other websites are loaded just fine.

Comment: I've added the code

Comment: What is the version of Android on the device you are testing this? Do other devices give you similar results? I am thinking its an older device issue.

Comment: I tested on API 23 and API 25. Both have same issue

Comment: Hi, I tested this app on API 18 and it is working fine. On 19 and above I am facing this issue. Do you have any idea?